# tkinter: scolledText occupies little space

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

This is my app so far:
[image]

The blue frame should contain a scrolledText widget.

This is the code that creates it:

```
# --- frame 2 ---
frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff') #remove color later
frame2.place(relx=0, rely=0.1, relheight=0.07, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')

# make a scrollbar
scrollbar = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(frame2)
scrollbar.place(relx=0, rely=0.1, relheight=0.07, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')
```

I want this widget to occupy the space from the area that is created, up to the end of the window.

However, as you can see it takes so little space.

How can i modify me values in order to make it full?

Thank you

Comment: .07 of a few hundred pixels is only going to be a few pixels. Why are you setting the relative height to such a tiny number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with this:

```
# --- frame 2 ---
frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff') #remove color later
frame2.place(relx=0, rely=0.1, relheight=1, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')

# make a scrollbar
scrollbar = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(frame2)
scrollbar.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')
```